# Python recursion variable state

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python function to take a string and a number and return a list containing repetitions of the string. For example

```
print func(3, 'aaa')
```

returns

```
['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
def func(times, data):
    if times > 0:
        return data.split() + func(times-1, data)
```

However, it's giving me a TypeError:

```
can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list.
```

I'm still a novice and I just read about recursion.

I would also like to know how to "carry over" the state of a variable from successive function calls, without having to define a global variable. Help please!

Comment: So what happens when `times == 0`? You are not returning anything in that case.

Comment: While this could be done with recursion, this problem seems simple enough to do without it

Comment: what's wrong with `['aaa']*3`

Comment: I think he's trying to get some practice with recursion, nothing wrong with that. But yes, `[data]*times` is probably the best way to do it otherwise.

Comment: ok: so long for `def func(nb,s):
        return [s]*nb
    
    print(func(3, 'aaa'))`

Comment: _"I would also like to know how to "carry over" the state of a variable from successive function calls, without having to define a global variable."_ Actually, this is exactly what you're doing with the `times` and `data` variables already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a base case  where times is 0, there you can just return an empty list:

```
def func(times, data):
    if times == 0:
        return []
    # no need for split, just wrap data in a list.
    return [data] + func(times-1, data)
```

In your code when times == 0, your function implicitly returns None so you are trying to add the result of the recursive calls to None. We should also probably use <= in the base case to catch negative input for times:

```
def func(times, data):
    if times <= 0:
        return []
    return [data] + func(times-1, data)
```

If we don't we would recurse infinitely and hit a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` as we would never hit the base case.

There is a nice online tool [python tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) that can visualise the steps so you can see exactly what is happening which would highlight why and where your code erros.

When you have a working solution  you could use [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz) which will create a nice png of the execution steps:

[image]

*Note: 1. The edges are numbered by the order in which they were traversed by the execution. 2. The edges are colored from black to grey to indicate order of traversal : black edges first, grey edge*s last.

Answer (score 0):

While @Padraic Cunningham has a good answer, here is a simple way to do it:

```
def func(number, content):
    return [content] * number
```

Or list comprehension:

```
def func(number, content):
    return [content for _ in range(number)]
```